# Is it possible to establish a P2P connection between two Android phones?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am able to connect 2 phones through Bluetooth. But is it possible to connect through the wireless network?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks
Pradeep

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can. Every phone has an IP address, so you can create an application that is a server on one phone and a client on the other phone and make a normal TCP or UDP client/server connection between the two phones. You have to get creative if the phones are on different wifi networks and/or behind firewalls. It's also highly likely that the phones have internal IP's when attached to the GSM networks of the providers, so you might not be able to make long distance connections easily.  In a LAN environment, on the same wifi network it should be a breaze. You can even use any number of broadcast discovery protocols to "discover" each other.

Comment: re-reading I think my answer was too technical, it seems like you just want to do a p2p connection "out of the box" (like bluetooth) and I don't think you can do this on Android out of the box. You'll need to write an application (i.e. for file transfer)